# Running load test on more than one site at the same time

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, blazemeter

I need to run same JMeter script on more than one site at the same time to test performace. I am trying to use one JMeter script and hit 10 sites at the same time
I have tried to use multi test feature in Blazemeter, but it is not maintainable as if there is a change i need to make in the script i will have to upload same script again which is time consuming.
Another option I had is to repeat the script 10 times in one JMeter file which will access 10 different site, but this solution sounds to be not correct and will then becomes high maintenance if I need to make a change to the file.

Please advise if you have faced this situation and what is the right solution for that.

Tools I am using:
JMeter for scripting which reads users from csv and
BlazeMeter for execution

Answer (score 1):

How about using BlazeMeter's [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) for this? You can reference only one JMeter .jmx script and override the [properties/variables](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables) to point it to different sites you need to test.

Below example demonstrates how to concurrently launch one script 2 times providing different `${hostname}` variable to them:

```
---
execution: 
#This is for site # 1
- scenario: 
    variables: 
      hostname: http://example.com
    script: Test.jmx
#This is for site # 2    
- scenario:
    variables: 
      hostname: http://jmeter.apache.org
    script: Test.jmx
#etc.
```

More information: [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests)